# Multidimensional array filter similar to mysql LIKE

Tags: php

This is my array:

```
$database[0] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789"); 
$database[1] = array("country"=>"USA", "product" => "pen123", "company" => "hi789"); 
$database[2] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789");
 $database[3] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789");
 $database[4] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen4023", "company" => "hi7789");
```

Output array that I want to get: "Country" = "UK" and "company" LIKE "ht%"

So, output will be:

```
$database[0] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789"); 
$database[2] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789");
 $database[3] = array("country"=>"UK", "product" => "pen423", "company" => "ht789");
```

Is it possible like sql statement and without using loop?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not working.

Comment: ^ Doesn't matter! Just include your attempt into your question and show your effort and work which you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use array_filter

```
function filterfunction($value) 
{

    if(strcmp($value['country'],"UK")!=0
      return false;
    if(strcmp(substr($value['company'],0,2),"ht")==0)
      return true;
    return false; 
}

$filterarr = array_filter($database, "filterfunction");
```

Comment: What is `strcomp()`? There's really no need for `$ret`, just return `true` or `false` to make the code more clear.

Comment: sorry it was typo of strcomp corrected now to strcmp. you are right regarding true/false return . just way of coding things other way but i agree with you and edited that too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). It accepts a callback where you can add custom logic to *filter* the result set.

Using string functions like `strpos()` or `substr()` should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: To preempt comments or down votes, this is a *teaching how to fish* answer provided the lack of code in the OP.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work here and right now, sadly. Because as long as someone provides copy&paste code which OP can use and it's not like midnight, OP will simply prefer/choose (to 99%) the easiest way for him and that will be the copy&paste code. So you won't get OP there, that he will research/use your clues and advices to try to solve the problem by himself and you will help him to get there, so that at the end OP could say he all have done it by himself and got it done! (Which would be the best way to get to a solution I think! And where OP has the most learning success!)

Comment: @Rizier123, agreed. Unfortunately, someone posted a copy/paste answer. Which of course was accepted ;)